# Copied and pasted code off IBM site, but I get a different result

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

I am playing around with posix semaphores, trying to get a better understand of them.  I copied this code from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apis/ipcsemge.htm?lang=en.

The output is supposed to be

> The initial value of the semaphore is 10 The value of the semaphore
>   after the wait is 9

Instead I get

> The initial value of the semaphore is 0 The value of the semaphore
>   after the wait is 0

Is there something wrong with the code?  I am using an xcode Version 3.2.6

Here is the code

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <semaphore.h>


  main() {
  sem_t my_semaphore;
  int value;

  sem_init(&my_semaphore, 0, 10);
  sem_getvalue(&my_semaphore, &value);
  printf("The initial value of the semaphore is %d\n", value);
  sem_wait(&my_semaphore);
  sem_getvalue(&my_semaphore, &value);
  printf("The value of the semaphore after the wait is %d\n", value);

}
```

Comment: You could try checking return values to see if anything is refusing for some reason ?

Comment: I am getting a Function not implemented error.  Any ideas of what that is?

Comment: Do you use -pthread option when compiling your code?

Comment: the sem_wait() function locks the semaphore (if the semaphore is not already locked.)  a locked semaphore has a value of 0.  If more (threads/processes) execute a sem_wait() on the same semaphore then the value is incremented negative (now less than 0) and waits until the semaphore is again above 0 before completing the function. (which will again set the value to 0)  Normally, the third parameter of the sem_init() function is 1, then the action is obvious.

Comment: additionally, when the third parameter is > 1, it is a count of the number of resources available.  Then each sem_wait decrements the value and when the value reaches 0, any following calls to sem_wait will block until some process that has a resource releases that resource by calling sem_post  However, most implementations of the semaphore do not allow for multiple resources to be allocated.

Comment: @nicky_zs - Yes I am using the -pthread option.  I have written a couple of smaller programs in Xcode on this computer using pthreads.

Comment: @user3629249, Wouldn't having the third parameter of the sem_init() being set to 10 set the values to 10?  Then calling wait would decrement this by 1 until  it gets to 0 and then wait until sem_post() is used and frees up one of the semaphores?

Comment: So this seems to be a mac issue using unnamed semaphores in Xcode.  I used the same exact code on eclipse in Ubuntu and it worked fine.